# Can XMLHTTPREQUEST.send use placeholders- trying to login to website with XMLHTTP

Tags: xml, vba, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to use XMLHTTP to log in to a website. I'm just curious as I think I may have stumbled upon a website which has taken measure to prevent automated logins but I'm not sure...

The website is: https://www.nordnet.se/mux/login/startSE.html?cmpi=start-loggain

Looking at the fields: Användarnamn ( Which is "Username") And Lösenord ( Which is "Password" )

We get the following when inspecting the code

For the username

```
<input type="text" class="form-control lowercase" placeholder="Användarnamn" id="input1" name="05b815966281833f744f3aafe2d8d907" autocomplete="off">
```

For the password

```
 <input id="pContent" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Lösenord" autocomplete="off">
    <input id="pContHidden" name="8ed7fbd0d02d475becd85807358088e3" type="hidden" autocomplete="off">
```

Now everytime one refreshes the website the "name" variable gets changed, this is in effect a measure to prevent people from running xmlhttprequest.send "username=****&password=******" ?

Would one be able to login using the placeholder attributes instead? As they do not change during refresh.

Also, why i there one row wotj input id = "pContent" and one input id= "pContHidden" for the password?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm in the same position (also NordNet)

Comment: I can't recall how far I got. But I remember not following through on the project. Nordnet however has an API available (that costs money, but not too much), you should probably first check that one out before building a solution like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placeholder attributes cannot be used but the id attributes can come handy for creating the login request body.

The POST request has got the body like `referer=&encryption=1&fake_password=&d1e3dc2fca672beb62f6290dae2fb11a=userID&39826874bfc57986d2ffc6b34ac2dd63=WUKqcVnoshIzOqAh8FvdV4NhDTMvCQ9EGqwnphGH29SOSN7jj6D39pYbTCMBdMmSGqQ6BPSQIremW%2FTIwrXfRw%3D%3D`

Here the password is encrypted into the "pContHidden" element having name `39826874bfc57986d2ffc6b34ac2dd63`. The "pContent" element is not used to pass any value.

The names of the elements can be found using `javascript:alert(document.getElementById("input1").name);` and `javascript:alert(document.getElementById("pContHidden").name);` in the browser adderss bar and pressing enter. Hence this can be directly derived from an XMLHttp response body loaded as an htmlfile object.

Still you would need to understand the encryption being used to create the password hash being submitted.

It would be easier if you use the internetExplorer object to navigate to the login page and then programatically fill the fields based on the id and then emulate a click on the logga In button.